# FastAPI + Uvicorn could not accept external connect

Tags: centos, fastapi, uvicorn

I planed to deploy OpenSearch with Python FastAPI + Uvicorn.
I upload FastAPI python script and start server with uvicorn command, only internal connection work and external not.

This is my env and and options.

CentOS7
python 3.9
fastapi 0.79.1
uvicorn 0.16.0

CORS setting...

```py
origins = [
    '*'
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=False,
    allow_methods=["POST"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
```

[uvicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAWqy.png)

host: 0.0.0.0
port: 5650

[port state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBvk6.png)

5650 port's state is LISTEN when I check netstat -tulnp
and also firewalld is disabled.

External Connection is possible with OpenSearch Node and Dashboards (port 9200, 5601)
Only FastAPI + Uvicorn couldn't...

Sorry for my short english...
I need some help...

Comment: Where are you deploying your API? If it is some kind of cloud VM (e.g. AWS EC2), they usually have separate access rules outside of the actual VM, that you would also need to configure.

Comment: Thanks! when I check additional firewall.  Iptables activated...